# Python. Delete "Unnamed: 0" header lable in dataframe and shift the rest of the header lables to the left (without altering values)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, header

I have a cross-tabulation `.txt` file of this shape:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A |  |  | 9.7 |  |
| B |  |  |  | 9.7 |
| C | 9.7 |  |  | 9.7 |
| D |  | 9.7 | 9.7 |  |

However, when I try to read it using

```py
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', index_col=0)
```

-where `file` is the location of this `.txt` file that I'm getting this data frame from-:

|  | Unnamed: 0 | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A |  |  | 9.7 |  | NaN |
| B |  |  |  | 9.7 | NaN |
| C | 9.7 |  |  | 9.7 | NaN |
| D |  | 9.7 | 9.7 |  | NaN |

As you can see, it shifts the column labels to the right by adding a new label (**"Unnamed: 0"**).

At this point, I'd only need to do three things:

1. To delete **Unnamed: 0** label in the header.
2. To shift the rest of the labels of the header to the left (to let the data frame recover its original shape).
3. To delete the last column (the one with all **NaN** values).

As I'm an absolute beginner in Python, I can't find the way to do so, although it's probably a very simple task.

For more information regarding how my `.txt` file is built -probably the origin of my problem-, here is the python code I'm using to create the cross-tab shown above (the first table pasted):

`file_path` is the path where I the cross-tab is created,

`unique_nodes` is a list where I store the unique nodes I work with. They are the column and row names of the cross-tab: `A, B, C, D`.

`node1` and `node2` are nodes from that list.

`node_weights` are the values of the cells in the table (in this case, 9.7)

```py
    with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
        # Write header row
        file.write('\t' + '\t'.join(unique_nodes) + '\n')
        
        # Write rows of cross-tab data
        for node1 in unique_nodes:  
            file.write(node1 + '\t')
            for node2 in unique_nodes:
                file.write(str(node_weights[node1][node2]) + '\t')
            file.write('\n')
```

Comment: Can you fix the file so the headers are properly aligned with the data? The problem seems to be that the TAB delimiters are not being used consistently.

Comment: Maybe the problem is just on the header line. I think it may have an extra TAB character before the `br1_2` header.

Comment: It's probably the root of my problem, as you point out. I edited my question including the code I use to generate the file, but the solution I needed was already given. Thank you for taking the time to read my post @Barmar

Comment: If would be better to provide the content of the text file (as raw text between triple backticks, not as table)

Comment: Any reason you're not writing a normal CSV file, using Python's built-in `csv` module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just shift the column names to the left by 1 and drop the last column.

```
df.columns = df.columns.to_list()[1:] + ['temp']
df = df.drop('temp', axis = 1)
```

Comment: Simple as that. Fantastic. Thank you @user19077881 !

Comment: `df = df.shift(axis=1).iloc[:, 1:]` without needing to manually change the names